# Cannot apply Git patch (replacing a file with a link)

Tags: git

In a Git repository I would like to replace an existing file with a soft link to a file outside the repository. (Just to make things clear, I want to reference a file automatically generated by an external tool.)

```
$ git rm FILE
$ ln -s PATH-TO-FILE FILE
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "..."
```

Everything is cool.
I git-format-patch out of this commit - no problem there.
But when I attempt to apply this patch ...

```
$ git am < PATCH
Applying: PATCH
fatal: unrecognized input
Patch failed at 0001 PATCH
...
```

git-apply produces similar, but less verbose, result.
Is there a way out of this situation ?
Is this behaviour normal at all, or is it a bug ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: After a little more trials, it looks like a bug in Git, because splitting the commit in two (git rm ... commit; ln -s ... commit) produces applicable patch.

Comment: I could not reproduce the behavior with git 1.8.4.3. I created a patch following your steps and `git format-patch -1` and then I switched back to the source branch and could apply the patch without issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was pointed out by @janos, this problem does not exist in newer git version.
Indeed, building (the recent) git from source solves the problem, so apparently there was a bug in format-patch.

Answer (score 0):

Try without the `<`:

```
git am PATCH
```

I was able to add symbolic link in this way.